# Using a list in a mask to filter out dates within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, filter, mask

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of the other question. This question is about filtering specific **dates** from a list using a mask. The other question (*How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL*) uses a totally different method of df.column.isin(). Furthermore, the other question uses categorical string object data to filter rather than datetime data.

Here is my attempt with .isin():

```
list_dates = [np.datetime64('2018-12-31'),np.datetime64('2019-01-01')]
df[~df['StartTime'].dt.date.isin(list_dates)]
```

output:

```
    StartTime   Duration    Site
0   2018-12-30 01:45:00 1   1
1   2018-12-31 05:48:00 1   2
2   2018-12-31 17:36:00 3   3
```

This output is obviously incorrect as in the list, I specified '2018-12-31' to be filtered out.

---

I have been learning how to use masks to filter out dates in a dataframe.

Firstly, here is the dataframe that I am testing on:

```
data = {'StartTime':['2018-12-30 12:45:00+11:00','2018-12-31 16:48:00+11:00','2019-01-01 04:36:00+11:00','2019-01-01 19:27:00+11:00','2019-01-02 05:13:00+11:00'],
        'Duration':[1,1,3,1,2],
        'Site':['1','2','3','4','5']    
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'])
```

Next, I am looking to filter out a single date. This works:

```
mask = (df['StartTime'].dt.date != np.datetime64('2019-01-01'))

df.loc[mask]
```

However, I want to do this for multiple dates, and it will be a pain to write the same line for multiple dates. Essentially, I would like to filter out a list of dates. For example, I would like to filter out all public holidays.

Can I do something like this?

```
list_of_holiday_dates = [np.datetime64('2019-01-01'), np.datetime64('2019-12-25')]

mask = (df['StartTime'] != list_of_holiday_dates)

df.loc[mask]
```

The reason being, the list will be something that needs updating regularly as public holidays are on different dates depending on the year.

---

AND just a second question for curiosity sake; Why is it when you make a mask you use `dt.date` , `dt.hour`, etc.

```
mask = (df['StartTime'].dt.date != np.datetime64('2019-01-01'))
```

BUT when you select/index it directly, you can't use .dt

```
# this works
df.iloc[0].StartTime.date
# this works
df.iloc[0].StartTime.dt.date()
# this doesn't work, but is used in the mask
df.iloc[0].StartTime.dt.date

# this works
df.iloc[0].StartTime.hour
# this doesn't work, but would be used in the mask
df.StartTime.dt.hour.between(6,9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert values to dates with convert array to `DatetimeIndex` and then by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
list_dates = [np.datetime64('2018-12-31'),np.datetime64('2019-01-01')]


df = df[~df['StartTime'].dt.date.isin(pd.DatetimeIndex(list_dates).date)]
print (df)
            StartTime  Duration  Site
0 2018-12-30 01:45:00         1     1
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it works! Could you please explain the methodology a bit more? I thought `np.datetime64('2018-12-31')` would be considered a datetime object already. Why do we have to further convert using `pd.DatetimeIndex`?

Comment: @meronpan - Reason is because I want convert values to `date`s, I think this is simpliest method, because exist `DatetimeIndex.date`. Alternative is use  `df = df[~df['StartTime'].dt.date.isin([pd.Timestamp(x).date() for x in list_dates])]`

Comment: @meronpan - Generally if need filter in pandas is necessary same types of data like filtered, here `dates` are filtered by `datetime`s, not by `date`s.